# Angular function fires before model is updated: Zipcode checker

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It seems like the checkZip function is firing BEFORE the user's zip is binded into the parameter. Is there a better way to accomplish this with an angular tool? I want to initiate the next step in the user flow as soon as they've typed a correct zipcode.

HTML

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Zipcode" ng-model="zip" ng-change="checkZip('{{zip}}')">
```

Javascript

```
// Zipcode Key
$scope.zipKey = [94203, 94204, 94205];

// Zipcode checker
$scope.checkZip = function(zip) {
    var key = $scope.zipKey;
    if (zip.length == 5) {  
        for(var i = 0;i<key.length;i++) {
            if (key[i] == zip) {
                // Initiate State Change
                $scope.successAlert = 'We serve in your area!';
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Don't pass the model back in, you already have access to it via `$scope.zip`

Comment: you can also wait for the $dirty filed on that form. That way you know it's been altered.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better use the angular form validation and write a custom validator.

Here is [a great article](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/validations.html) covering everything you need to know about it.

For your needs, you could write a directive like this one:

```
app.directive('ensureZipcode', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelController) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
        valid = true // or false, implement your logic here
        modelController.$setValidity('zipcode', valid);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Small note here: modelController is set as a fourth parameter of the `link` function because we specified `require: 'ngModel'`.

Comment: You're not using `$http`, probably don't need to include it

Comment: A custom validator is great for something like a zip code so that you can ensure it's in the correct format using a regex or something of the like

Comment: `ng-pattern="/a-zA-Z/"` can be enough.